# RegEX does not matches until end of line

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the String Hex-STRING until the end of line. But what it matches is `Hex-STRING: 84 16 F9 B0 05 1F 70 4F 57 4C A8 1F 60 E3 27 A1
E0 CD C4 E9 84 C3 68 53 C4 E9 84 C9 7A BB C4 E9 84 AC`.

Something is missing in this expression? I already tried to include `$`but it does not work.

RegEX: `Hex-STRING:\s(.+)`

Test String:

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.4.2.13.36 = Hex-STRING: 84 16 F9 B0 05 1F 70 4F 57 4C A8 1F 60 E3 27 A1
E0 CD C4 E9 84 C3 68 53 C4 E9 84 C9 7A BB C4 E9 84 AC 
C3 68 53 27 CC 58 97 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC 58 97
84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC 58 97 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27
CC 58 97 
84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 C3 68 53 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC 
58 97
```

### Python Code

Text File content:

```
 iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.3.2.1.11.1.2.4 = STRING: "785c720855c8"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.2.4.9 = Hex-STRING: 84 16 F9 AF CF 75 84 16 F9 AF E1 35 50 C7 BF F2
F8 4B 70 4F 57 3A C6 23 70 4F 57 3E C5 CD
```

Code:

```
w = open("text.txt","r")
 for item in w:
  for match in re.findall(r'Hex-STRING:\s*(.+)',item):
   print match
```

Output:

```
84 16 F9 AF CF 75 84 16 F9 AF E1 35 50 C7 BF F2
```

Output Expected:

```
84 16 F9 AF CF 75 84 16 F9 AF E1 35 50 C7 BF F2
F8 4B 70 4F 57 3A C6 23 70 4F 57 3E C5 CD
```

Comment: It seems to work, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ebNGlI/1), `84 16 F9 B0 05 1F 70 4F 57 4C A8 1F 60 E3 27 A1` is captured. What is the code you are using the regex in? Do you need to match till the end of *line* or *string*?

Comment: So, do you want it to end with `58 97`, or `27 A1`?

Comment: `"Hex-STRING:\s(.+)"s` ?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew I dont have sure how it works, but I thought that that expression should matches `Hex-STRING` and all these numbers, until `.. 27 CC 
58 97`

Comment: Then you need to add `(?s)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ebNGlI/2)

Comment: Does your document end at `27 CC 58 97`?

Comment: Yes, I will updated my question with my code, one moment please

Comment: I don't think that question what you marked would resolve this problem, but I'll read and test it @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You need to read the whole file in to make it work, but it *will* work. Remove `for item in w:`, and use `for match in re.findall(r'(?s)Hex-STRING:\s*(.+)', w.read()):`

Comment: hmm.. Worked! If I have loop the file and then apply regex, what should I use?

Comment: *If I have loop the file* - how do you plan to use a regex spanning across multiple lines then?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import re

text = """iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.4.2.13.36 = Hex-STRING: 84 16 F9 B0 05 1F 70 4F 57 4C A8 1F 60 E3 27 A1
E0 CD C4 E9 84 C3 68 53 C4 E9 84 C9 7A BB C4 E9 84 AC
C3 68 53 27 CC 58 97 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC 58 97
84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC 58 97 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27
CC 58 97
84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 C3 68 53 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC
58 97"""

result = re.search("Hex-STRING:\s(.+)$", text, re.DOTALL)
print(result.group())
```

**Output**

```
Hex-STRING: 84 16 F9 B0 05 1F 70 4F 57 4C A8 1F 60 E3 27 A1
E0 CD C4 E9 84 C3 68 53 C4 E9 84 C9 7A BB C4 E9 84 AC
C3 68 53 27 CC 58 97 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC 58 97
84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC 58 97 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27
CC 58 97
84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 C3 68 53 84 AC 74 F7 60 E3 27 CC
58 97
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character
>   including a newline.

Comment: Please, I updated my question with my code

Comment: See the answers to the duplicated question or ask a new question